# C# override properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control which has Textbox and Panel. I need to transfer from the panel ForeColor in textbox. I do so but does not work.

```
public Color ForeColor
{
    get
    {
        return transparentTextBox.ForeColor;
    }
    set
    {
        transparentTextBox.ForeColor = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Have you used any debugging or breakpoints to see what is going on? If transparentTextBox defined?

Comment: Do not quite understand

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work". Does it throw exception?

Comment: "does not work". Does not change color Font

Comment: @mzk `a control which has TextBox and Panel` -> You should post more code to make this clearer.

Comment: I think `transparentTextBox.ForeColor = panel.Forecolor` is what you're looking for

Comment: Judging from the question title, I'd say he's looking for: public *override* Color ForeColor ...

Answer (score 0):

Do this in steps:

1. Do not expose the `TextBox` and `Panel` to the outside world, make them private controls (private to the `Control` that contains them). Your control may expose properties such as Text (which then gets/sets the same property on the TextBox).
2. Expose a `PanelColor` property that is of type `Color`. When this property is set, set that color in both the `Panel` and the `TextBox`.

This way, your `Control` only exposes the properties that it has to (the [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) principle) and you can react to property changes any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what's that property is, but it's not an `override` and not an event handler so there is no way it will work. i think the best way to do what you want is just set

```
transparentTextBox.ForeColor = pnl.ForeColor;
```

in the initialize of the control.

if someone else is going to change the panel's foreColor then make a method or property that do

```
pnl.ForeColor = givenValue;//givenValue is the value the user gave to change the panel's foreColor
transparentTextBox.ForeColor = givenValue;
```

for example this userControl do that:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
  private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
  private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
  public UserControl1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
     this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
     this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
     this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 14);
     this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
     this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
     this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 15);
     this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
     this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
     this.textBox1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);

     textBox1.ForeColor = panel1.ForeColor;
  }

  public Color ForeColor
  {
     get
     {
        return textBox1.ForeColor;
     }
     set
     {
        panel1.ForeColor = value;
        textBox1.ForeColor = value;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Who said anything about an event handler? OP is trying to expose a property of an inner object to the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox // custom textbox
{
    protected override void OnParentForeColorChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        ForeColor = Parent.ForeColor;

        Invalidate();
        base.OnParentForeColorChanged(e);
    }
}
```

But there is other solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Color _foreColor = null;

public Color ForeColor
{
    get
    {
        if(_forecolor == null)
        {
         _foreColor = transparentTextBox.ForeColor;
        }

        return _foreColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Instead of overriding ForeColor property do this :

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ForeColorChanged += UserControl1_ForeColorChanged;
    } 

    void UserControl1_ForeColorChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.ForeColor = ForeColor;
    }
```

Not a really beautiful approch but it works :)